# try to get a value from HTML but get unexpected value

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping

I try to extract the pe ratio from this website:
https://www.ishares.com/uk/individual/en/products/251787/

I am trying to use the `from lxml import html` method which i see on a number of websites.

I get the xpath using `tree = html.fromstring(requests.get(url))`

i use two different methods:
[1] `val1 = tree.xpath(xp)`
[2] `val2 = tree.xpath(xp+'/text()')`

Here is the sample code:

```
# global imports
import requests
from lxml import html

'''
function to get data given a url and xpath
'''
def aFunctionForHTML(url, xp):

    #get the data
    resp = requests.get(url)

    if resp.status_code != 200:
        # This means something went wrong.
        print(resp.status_code)
        return None

    # generate the html tree
    tree = html.fromstring(resp.content)

    # get the xpath value
    val1 = tree.xpath(xp)
    val2 = tree.xpath(xp+'/text()')
    val = (val1, val2)
    return val



# the code starts here.
if __name__ == "__main__":

    url = 'https://www.ishares.com/uk/individual/en/products/253741/?switchLocale=y&siteEntryPassthrough=true'
    xp = '//*[@id="fundamentalsAndRisk"]/div/div[7]/span[2]'

    z = aFunctionForHTML(url, xp)
    print(z)
```

The value that  get is inside this `<span>`. In this case **10.91**.

```
<span class="data">
10.91
</span>
```

The response produces a result (using 2 different methods).
However the return value (as a tuple) is:
`([<Element span at 0x1d0dce655e8>], ['\n21.79\n'])`

**How can i get the 10.91 ?**

Answer (score 0):

Your `aFunctionForHTML` function returns a tuple where the first element is a reference to the actual HTML element, and the second value is a list containing the contents of that element. In order to get *just* the text from `z`, try this:

```
text = z[1][0].strip()
print(text)
```

will print

```
"21.79"
```

which is the updated P/E ratio.

Alternatively you can update your `aFunctionForHTML` function to only return the contents of the element with

```
return val2[0].strip()
```

and then just print the return value (in this case `z`)

Comment: I changed code to `  `val = tree.xpath(xp+'/text()')`  and then  `text = z[0].strip()`  as per your suggestion and this worked.   So from this i learn that **tree.xpath** is an array.

Comment: @DarrenLefcoe that's correct, because a single selection can return multiple elements. if this answer helped you, consider upvoting/accepting

Comment: i did up-vote. However, rank < 15 means it does not show publicly.